# Deploy ASP.NET CORE to Production

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that I need to deployed to production. I configured Junkins to use the use VS 2019 MsBuild and Nuget.

While running the build via Jenkins I am geeting the following error message:

```
  error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

In my production env there is no SDK since from what I understand I only need the runtime.

```
dotnet --info
 It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
     https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Host (useful for support):
 Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

 .NET Core SDKs installed:
      No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Do I need the SDK ? And if so why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need the SDK?

Yes.

> And if so why?

To build the code you need SDK not the runtime. If there's no SDK Jenkin cannot build the source.

Comment: But what about the MSbuild tool?

Comment: Which version of MSbuild are you using?

Comment: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.2+e481bbf88 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

16.3.2.50909

Comment: You see MsBuild is part of .Net Framework, MsBuild needs dotnet core SDK to build the dotnet core source.

Comment: You can also check manually using the command line `path_to_\MSBuild.exe path_to_.sln /T:Clean /T:Rebuild`

Comment: Well, it's a bit confusing. Anywhy thank you very much for clarifying this.